# Calling a static method from within another static method

Tags: php, static, amfphp

I'm using amfphp to connect my php with my flex application. I'm facing the following problem.

With amfphp the methods you want to call from flex need to have the following method-syntax:

```
public static function ...
```

My problem is when I want to call another static method from within this method, it says 
that the method does not exist.
Example:

```
public static function a(){
 call_user_func('b');
}

public static function b(){
 //do something
}
```

I have tried using the `call_user_func('methodname')` but it does not work, I've scooped around for a little but i could nog find the answer. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static function a()
{
  self::b();
  // or
  call_user_func('TTest::b');
}
```